# SQLite Database creation

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have written a code for SQLite database for creation of database and table but not inserted any row in it. So when(runtime or Compile time) does the database get created and How to check whether the database is created or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The database is created in `/data/data/[package name]/databases` in a `.db` file, so check to see if it was created in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function

```
private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
    //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
    checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

where DB_PATH will be /data/data/package_name/ and DB_NAME will be the name of the database. For example you create db by name android.db name will be android.